# How to Creating View And View Model For Two Related Entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

i have two entity: 
  1) student 
  and 2) address.

```
public class Student 
{
    Public Int StudentId { get; set; }
    Public String FullName { get; set; }

    Public virtual IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    Public Int AddressId { get; set; }
    Public Int StudentId { get; set; }
    Public String FullAddress { get; set; }

    Public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

each student may have zero or more address.

i want to create single view for this two entity. i know that must create a view model. this is view model.

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    Public Int StudentId { get; set; }
    Public String FullName { get; set; }
    public Address AddAddressModel { get; set; }

    Public virtual IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

and i create a view for StudentViewModel. this is StudentViewModel:

```
@model MyProject.Models.StudentViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
 }

 @using (Html.BeginForm ())
 {
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddAddressModel.FullAddress)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddAddressModel.FullAddres)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddAddressModel.FullAddres)
        </div>

        <button id="add">add address to list</button>

        <input type="submit" value="save in database" />        
</fieldset>
```

please tell me how i can add one or more address on by one in Addresses Property of StudentViewModel and show after this operation to user. finally when i click on the "save in database" button student and his addresses must be inserted in database.

Answer (score 1):

I have in the past submitted nested child entities, but that was always done with an API call and the form was serialized to a JSON object before submission.

Because you only really need multiple `FullAddress` values, you could change your model and view accordingly (not tested):

**Model:**

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string[] Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

In your view, when you click the 'Add' button, make sure that (through JavaScript) you end up with something like this:

```
<textarea name="Addresses[]">Some Address 1</textarea>
<textarea name="Addresses[]">Some Address 2</textarea>
etc...
```

Comment: thank you CornéM, but i want to use my model. bacause i want to extend this model to complex model like this: factory and his branches. please tell me more about first solution: serializing form to JSON Object before form submission

Comment: Hi, you can serialize forms to complex JSON objects using this plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8407771/1746803. You can then simply use `$.post()` to send the object to your script. I have used this solution many times with complex models and it has yet to fail me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using:

```
@EditorFor(m => model.Addresses)
```

this will create template for your address model

Comment: thank you, but bigger problem is how to save addresses bofore click on "save in database" button and insert this data in database after click.

Comment: yes when u post the form, you should get values under yourviewmodel.Addresses.AddressId or yourviewmodel.Addresses.FullAddress

Comment: how i add address to list before form submission? jQuery has any help for me? after sumbit of form, in Create Action Method i want to access student addresses by writing model.Addresses